# which priority order SQS message placed after visibility timeout?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

which priority order SQS message placed after visibility timeout?

if my SQS message visibility timeout after 2 minutes, 
in which order that this SQS message will get received again after 2 minutes ?

is that placed in random / first priority / last priority ?

Comment: do you use standard or FIFO queues?

Answer (score 1):

Its random - unless you are using the new FIFO queues, you can't control or predict the order of the messages you will receive on each call to get a new batch.

Comment: Is it really random/undefined, or is it "first...ish?"  If I have, say, 10K visible messages, wouldn't I get the newly-visible message again sooner rather than later?  I don't think it's documented but anecdotally, I *think* that's what I've observed... though it's been a while.

Comment: Not random in the sense of deliberately randomized, I mean random in that you simply can't count on it coming in any other way, and you need to assume its random.

Comment: how many percent it will be in front of the queue ?
SQS Standard promise the best effort to persist the sequence, so what will be the best effort for the reappear message ?

Imagine if there is 10k messages in the queue, when the old message reappear where it likely to be placed ? 

around first, middle, or at the back or just totally random which means can be at the back, can be at the first or middle ?

I need to consider this, to predict how long the old message will get reprocessed once it reappear to the queue

Comment: @E.J.Brennan Thanks for the answer. Could you also clarify where the messages are placed in the case of FIFO queues?